# Create New AD-User and Count if found

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am attempting to implment a script to help automate account creation.  It will query AD for a user and if found, add a number to the end, and then do another query.  Again, if found, change the number from say 2 - 3.

Such as if the following users are already in AD:

- Smith, James W  = SmithJW
- Smith, Jason W  = SmithJW2

I want to add a new user, Smith, Jacob W.  It should query AD for SmithJW at first, then if found, add a 2, and if found, add a 3.  What I got two work below, essentially does it, but due to it finding a SmithJW2, it just adds the counter to that name.  So I would get back SmithJW22.

Code:

```
$user = "smithjw"

Do{
    $adcheck = $null
    $counter = 2

 Try {$adcheck = Get-Aduser $user
     }  
  Catch {If($adcheck.SamAccountName-eq$null){$NewUserName = $user}
        }

    If($adcheck.SamAccountName-ne$null){$user = $user+$counter++}
  }until($adcheck.SamAccountName-eq$null)
```

So I'm looking for a way to if I find a user (i.e. SmithJW2) to remove the "2" first, then add the counter.

Hopefully this makes sense.  Thanks.

Comment: If you put the "++" after the variable name, it is incremented AFTER it is used in the expression; if you do "++$counter" instead, it will add 1 to counter before being evaluated, which would probably do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution that does not involve try catch statements in case there are other issues with `Get-AdUser`.

```
$accountname = "account"
$count = $null
do{
    $query = "(&(objectClass=user)(samaccountname=$accountname$count))"
    $result = ([adsisearcher]$query).FindOne()
    If($result){If($count -eq $null){$count = 2}Else{$count++}}
}While($result)

Write-Host "The account name you should use is: $accountname$count"
```

`[adsisearcher]$query).FindOne()` would return `$null` if there is not object found. So loop until `$result` is empty/null. I'm not happy with how the `$count` is handled but it does work. The `$count` is changed if there is a returned user. If there is the `$count` needs to be changed. Since you start 2 we need to check if its the first time the variable is going to be set. There are other ways but this is consistent and readable. (I have an idea using `Get-Variable` but it's needlessly complicated.)

Answer (score 1):

Here's roughly how I would do this (NOTE: untested, since my AD doesn't use this naming scheme):

```
$samAccountName = 'smithjw'
$count = 2
if (Get-ADUSer $samAccountName -ErrorAction Silently Continue) {
    while (Get-ADUser "$samAccountName$Count" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        $count++
    }
    #create "$samAccountName$count"
}
else {
    #just create smithjw
}
```

Comment: Thanksf for the reply.  Testing the above I get back tons of errors `Get-ADUser : Cannot find an object with identity: 'smithjw3' under: 'DC=my,DC=domain,DC=dom'.At line:1 char:11 + Get-ADUSer <<<<  $samAccountName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (smithjw3:ADUser) [Get-ADUser], ADIdentityNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Cannot find an object with identity: 'smithjw3' under: 'DC=my,DC=domain,DC=dom'.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser`  It seems the Get-Aduser doesn't like the -EA action.

Comment: Oh, you're right (told you it was untested ;) ); looks like you'll have to do try/catch around Get-ADUser when you expect it to fail.

Comment: I was able to use what you provided to come up with a solution.  `$samAccountName = "smithjw"

   $adcheck = $null
   $count = 2
   try {
        $adcheck = get-aduser $samAccountName
        If ($adcheck.SamAccountName-ne$null) {while (Get-ADUser "$samAccountName$count"){$count++}
             }
    
        else {$NewUserName = $samaccountname}
       } 
   
   catch {
          $NewUserName = "$samAccountName$count"
         }`