# adsisearcher error: "The (mail=john.doe)) search filter is invalid"

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a question, regarding mail address-generation logic. It'll start by assuming `FirstName.Lastname`, and check if that's already in AD.

If it already exists, it will add numbers of the end last-name until it finds an unused mail address:

`john.doe@contoso.com`, `john.doe2@contoso.com`, `john.doe3@contoso.com`, etc.

Note: we have the first name as `$FirstName` and the last name as `$LastName`

```
$count = $null
do {
    $query = "(mail=$username$count))"
    $result = ([adsisearcher]$query).FindOne()
    if ($result) {if ($count -eq $null) {$count = 2} else {$count++}}
} while ($result)

Write-Host "The account name you should use is: $username$count"
```

Here my error message is:

> Exception calling "FindOne" with "0" argument(s): "The (mail=john.doe)) search filter is invalid."
>   At line:5 char:45

Comment: As the error states `"The (mail=john.doe)) search filter is invalid." `, you're using an invalid search-filter. Maybe this link helps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Assume somewhere else in your script you set `$username = "$FirstName.$LastName`

Comment: you are right man. I am using $username = $Firstname+"."+$Lastname

Comment: Seeing as you've copied your code line-for-line from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27624077/create-new-ad-user-and-count-if-found maybe you need to have a look at what you removed from the `$query` to see why it's erroring.

Comment: Your search filter has a spurious closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i'm understand you well, you want to find the next available email address and add 1 to the end of it in case it it exist?

if so, you can use this simple function:

add your input as email format, and it will add 1 until it not found it, and return the available mail

```
Function Get-AvailableMail()
{
Param(
$Email
)

$i = 1

    while (([adsisearcher]"(&(mail= $($Email)))").FindOne())
    {
    $Email = ($Email -split '@')[0] + "$i@" + ($Email -split '@')[1]
    $i++
    }

    return $Email

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much man. My last question : I want to get only the value left to "@"  within $Email variable with Powershell. For example, if mail address is User1@domain.com, I would like to retrieve only User1.

Comment: you mean in the output? if so change `return $Email` to `return ($Email -split '@')[0]`